# How can I indent the text, and starting position of cursor, in a TextBox (user, password, etc..)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login form, with username and password input fields.

These boxes have shadows, and when you click the box, the cursor blinks in the shadow and you can barely see it.

I want someone to click in the text box and have the cursor blink at a 3px indent from the left of the text box.  How do I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your input have a class on the css file? If yes, you should add the element `padding-left: 3px;` to that class.

If not, you should add `style="padding-left: 3px;"` to the input tag in your html.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `padding-left: 3px;` to the input box's style. Keep in mind that if you want the input box width to stay the same, you'll want to subtract 3px from its width as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your textboxes:

`style="padding-left: 3px"`

Or this:

`style="text-indent: 3px"`

Answer (score 0):

Using a padding would be the best way. `style="padding-left: 3px;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `text-indent` css property.

```html
<input style="text-indent:16px"/>
```